# Restore Classic System Properties [Control Panel]

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-11

When you right-click on `This PC`, and click `Properties`, the latest versions of Windows (`20H2` or later) will show you a modern About window available in the Settings app, as shown in the image:
[image: About window - Windows Settings]

But in previous versions of Windows (below build `20161`), it opened the System Properties window available in Control Panel, as shown in the image:
[image: System - Control Panel]

I'm looking for a solution to replace the command that Properties does; To open Classic System Properties instead of the About window.

Please don't tell me this is not possible. Hope you unlock this solution!

Comment: I must admit, the new applet does in fact suck horribly. but I feel that way about most of the new Settings applets. Still trying to figure out how to get to playback and recording device configuration from the Audio settings.

Comment: Welcome to windows system/control panel sucking more and more since windows 7.  No matter how much we hates it, Microsoft keeps cramming it down our throats and telling us that we really like it.  Then they make it worse.

Comment: How are we supposed to fix this one? The most that can be done is to add somewhere a shortcut for easy access to it.

Comment: on win11, it doesn't even ship with system.cpl. not sure about win10. I wanna say I think it was still there last time I looked. at least appwiz.cpl still works.... for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old interface is still accessible by running this command from Start/Run dialog:

- `shell:::{bb06c0e4-d293-4f75-8a90-cb05b6477eee}`

Maybe you can try AutoHotkey to launch the above command when the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key is pressed.

*(Src: [How to Add OEM Information and Logo in Windows 10](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-oem-logo-information-system-information-windows/))*

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the settings in the [Explorer Patcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) program, as [documented in its wiki](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/wiki/All-features#prevent-the-following-control-panel-links-from-being-redirected-to-the-settings-app).